# Counting days in java

Tags: java, date

I don't really know exactly how to explain this but basically the user is asked how many times, say they say 2. It will ask the user to input a month, day and year in numerical form. Then it will do it again because they said 2. It spits out a date in (Saturday, January 8th, 2014) format for each date they put in. So what I want is:

```
There were X dates on Sunday
There were X dates on Monday
There were X dates on Tuesday
There were X dates on Wednesday
There were X dates on Thursday
There were X dates on Friday
There were X dates on Saturday
```

How can I make java recognize the day of week and then add one to it so I can replace X above.

I have variables for each day, for example int saturday. I know I have to do saturday++; somewhere but I don't know where. I tried a switch and case but it doesn't know

```
case Monday:
```

because Monday is no where in my code, I used a simple date format.

Does this make sense? Should I post my code? Warning its like 300 lines.

As Pshemo said "In short, I want the user to say how many "events" occurred, pass their dates and print how many of then happened in each day of week"

Comment: In short, you want user to say how many "events" occurred, pass their dates and print how many of then happened in each day of week?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to format your `SimpleDateFormat` using an `E`, which will output the day of the week. Than compare that Date as a String with your weekdays, e.g. `day.equals("Monday")`.

Reference to SimpleDateFormat: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 2):

The days of the week are int constants in `java.util.Calendar`. You can find it using:

```
int dayOfTheWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is some example code using the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3 library.

The day-of-week is an interpretation based on the **time zone**. In Joda-Time, a DateTime object actually knows its own time zone, unlike a java.util.Date which *seems* to have a time zone but does not. Think about whether you want each DateTime object to use its own time zone to determine day-of-week or you way want to convert the objects to a common time zone for comparison.

```java
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" );

java.util.List<DateTime> dateTimes = new java.util.ArrayList<DateTime>();
dateTimes.add( new DateTime( 2014, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, timeZone ) );  // Thursday
dateTimes.add( new DateTime( 2014, 1, 3, 3, 4, 5, timeZone ) );  // Friday
dateTimes.add( new DateTime( 2014, 1, 9, 3, 4, 5, timeZone ) );  // Thursday
System.out.println( "Date-Time objects…" );
System.out.println( dateTimes );

// Make a list of 7 elements, one element per each day of week.
// Each element stores a count of events occurring on that day of week.
// Using standard ISO 8601 week, Monday first, Sunday last.
java.util.List<Integer> days = new java.util.ArrayList<Integer>( 7 );
for ( int i = 0; i < 7; i++ ) {
    days.add( new Integer( 0 ) ); // Initial all counts to zero.
}

for ( DateTime dateTime : dateTimes ) {
    int dayOfWeekNumber = dateTime.getDayOfWeek(); // Retrieve day-of-week number, 1-7. Monday is first.
    int index = ( dayOfWeekNumber - 1 ); // Index/Zero-based counting, so subtract 1 from ordinal.
    Integer oldIntegerCount = days.get( index );  // Retrieve the previous count for this day-of-week.
    Integer newIntegerCount = ( oldIntegerCount + 1 ); // Increment old count to new count object.
    days.set( index, newIntegerCount ); // Replace old Integer object with freshly incremented Integer object.
}

// Report results.
// Joda-Time does not have a convenient list of days of week to iterate. So the following code is a bit goofy.
// The java.time.* package in Java 8 does have the nice feature of a fancy Enum for days-of-week.
for ( int i = 0; i < days.size(); i++ ) {
    LocalDate date = new LocalDate();
    date = date.withDayOfWeek( i + 1 ); // Add one to transform index into ordinal.
    System.out.println( "There were " +  days.get( i )  + " dates on " + date.dayOfWeek().getAsText() );
}
```

When run…

```
Date-Time objects…
[2014-01-02T03:04:05.000+01:00, 2014-01-03T03:04:05.000+01:00, 2014-01-09T03:04:05.000+01:00]
There were 0 dates on Monday
There were 0 dates on Tuesday
There were 0 dates on Wednesday
There were 2 dates on Thursday
There were 1 dates on Friday
There were 0 dates on Saturday
There were 0 dates on Sunday
```